# Kendo grid column - show text when editing

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a `kendo grid` in a page
I need to show a text when the user start editing a specified column from the grid.

Here is the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GGISServices.Models.SilviPrio.GenerateDocumentViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Columns(columns =>
        { ...
          columns.Bound(c => c.TreeQ4)
                .HeaderTemplate("<a class='k-link' href=''>"+ LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Enum_TreeGroup_4") +"<br><span class='subtitle'>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Trees_MeasurementUnits") + "</span></a>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tree-q4 pvrf-data tree-column" }).Sortable(true)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'TreeQ4', fieldtype: 'decimal' }"))));
            columns.Bound(c => c.TreeQ1)
                .HeaderTemplate("<a class='k-link' href=''>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Enum_TreeGroup_1") + "<br><span class='subtitle'>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Trees_MeasurementUnits") + "</span></a>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tree-q1 pvrf-data tree-column" }).Sortable(true)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'TreeQ1', fieldtype: 'decimal' }"))));
            columns.Bound(c => c.TreeQ2)
                .HeaderTemplate("<a class='k-link' href=''>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Enum_TreeGroup_2") + "<br><span class='subtitle'>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Trees_MeasurementUnits") + "</span></a>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tree-q2 pvrf-data tree-column" }).Sortable(true)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'TreeQ2', fieldtype: 'decimal' }"))));
            columns.Bound(c => c.TreeQ5)
                .HeaderTemplate("<a class='k-link' href=''>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Enum_TreeGroup_5") + "<br><span class='subtitle'>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Trees_MeasurementUnits") + "</span></a>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tree-q5 pvrf-data tree-column" }).Sortable(true)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'TreeQ5', fieldtype: 'decimal' }"))));
            columns.Bound(c => c.TreeQ3)
                .HeaderTemplate("<a class='k-link' href=''>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Enum_TreeGroup_3") + "<br><span class='subtitle'>" + LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Trees_MeasurementUnits") + "</span></a>")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tree-q3 pvrf-data tree-column" }).Sortable(true)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'TreeQ3', fieldtype: 'decimal' }"))));
            columns
              .Bound(c => c.SilviPrioId)
              .ClientTemplate(
                  "#= actionDetails(data) #"
              )
              .Title(LanguageService.Instance.Translate("GridLabel_Action"))
              .Filterable(false)
              .Sortable(false)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "action-column" });
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        //.Selectable(selection => selection.Enabled(true))
        .Selectable(selection => selection.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
        //.Events(e => e.DataBound("SaveState").ExcelExport("ShowLoading"))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .Info(true)
            .PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000 })
            .ButtonCount(5)
            )
        .Events(events => events
            .Change("onChange")
            .DataBound("onDataBound")
            .DataBinding("onDataBounding")
            .Edit("onEditing")
            .SaveChanges("onSavingChanges")
        )
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .Events(events => events
                .Error("error_handler")
                .RequestEnd("request_end_handler")
            )
            .Model( model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.SilviPrioId);
                model.Field(p => p.Region).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.CostCenter).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.UP).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.UA).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.MeasurementUnit).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.PlannedQuantity).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.PlannedUnitPrice).Editable(false);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Editing_Update", "Document", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.SilviPrio }).Data("additionalUpdateInfo"))
            .PageSize(25)
        )
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

I need to show a text, something like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjzvP.png)
 but immediately when the user starts editing the fields `TreeQ4, TreeQ1`
I have searched on the net, and I have founded something with the `HtmlAttributes(title`, but it is not working like this.
Can you please advise how can I resolve?

Comment: Just for clarification. You want to show text somewhere on the page when the grid is in edit mode or show some custom text within the row when it is in edit mode?

Comment: @gardarvalur -  I have edited the question. I need to show a text when within a row a column is in edit mode. Now I show that text for a field at validation, when I have errors, but I need to show that immediately when I start editing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the kendo grid edit event and then append the text to a html element in the event function.